# Is there a way to show tasks input/output on BPMN Kogito tooling VSCode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, bpmn, jboss-tools, kogito

I just installed [Kogito VSCode extension](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-tooling/releases) for editing bpmn files, as described [here](https://porcelli.me/announcement/tooling/vscode/bpmn/2019/09/11/new-vscode-gui-editor.html). It's still on Alpha, but I'd like to know whether it is able to show input/ouput variables from custom service tasks.

I tried opening a bpmn file I created on kie-wb, and although it renders corectly, the input and output variables from our custom services are not shown on the details of the tasks.
I tried creating a new file from scratch and if I use the regular service task the option is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

custom Service Tasks needs support of Work Item Definitions (WID) and WID are not supported in Alpha version of Kogito VSCode extension.

Regular Service Task doesn't use WID mechanism, so Inputs/Outputs work there.